# Map Click and drawing item

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been looking this but haven't found a concrete example. Is there a way to click a specific point on a Map and then draw a overlayitem it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `onTouchEvent()` and use that to determine where a user taps. [Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/) that uses this for drag-and-drop of `OverlayItems`.

Comment: It really help me a lot i also had a problem on drawing but no big deal thanks!!